# LaTeX \hrule exceed tabularx width

Tags: latex

Here's my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{sfmX}
            \noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}
            \rowcolor{orange!85} Version & Date & Autore & Description \\
            \noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}
            1.1.1 & 2016-01-11 & Person 1 & Action 1  \\    
            \noalign{\hrule height 0.5pt}
            1.1.0 & 2016-01-10 & Person 2 & Action 2 \\ 
            \noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Diary \label{tab:table_label}}
    \end{table}
```

with:

```
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.22\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{f}{>{\hsize=.4\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
```

Result: 
[image: Result]

Is there any way to remove the exceed of `\noalign{\hrule}`s?
Can-t find out why tabularx won-t take all that space, or why rules take too much!

Comment: I got the solution by myself: it wasn't the \hline that exceeded the color, it was the color that wasn't covering all the table. That was caused by the columns % not getting to exact 100%. Giving 0.2, 0.4, 0.4 solved that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually the coloured header row being shorter than the `\hrule`s, as they fit nicely within `\textwidth`. Also, your choice for column `s` is too narrow.

Instead, I would suggest forgoing the use of your `\hrule`s, since you can use the constructions already available in [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\colorlet{headcol}{orange!85}

\newcommand{\headcol}{\rowcolor{headcol}}
\newcommand{\toprulec}{\arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{0.1em}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{headcol}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}}
\newcommand{\midrulec}{\arrayrulecolor{headcol}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l l l X}
  \toprulec
  \headcol Version & Date & Autore & Description \\
  \midrulec
  1.1.1 & 2016-01-11 & Person 1 & Action 1  \\    
  1.1.0 & 2016-01-10 & Person 2 & Action 2 \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```